# Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have login Method in LoginActivity which calling AsyncTask class methods .

That methods taking UserName And pass from SharedPrefrences Doing someQuery through SOAP webservice and return to reslut THE TeacherID if == 1 go Next activity .

But Once i Opened LoginActivity after Splash screen getting this LOG error :

LOG ERROR :

```
             FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.hesham.sams/com.hesham.sams.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:139)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:65)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:142)
        at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:359)
        at com.hesham.sams.LoginActivity.<init>(LoginActivity.java:79)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2025)
        ... 11 more
```

LoginActivity :

```
 loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                    LoginActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("جاري تسجيل الدخول الرجاء الانتظار");
            progressDialog.show();

            AsyncTaskWebServiceCaller MyTask = new AsyncTaskWebServiceCaller(
                    LoginActivity.this, progressDialog,
                    getApplicationContext());
            MyTask.execute();

        }
    });
```

FULL AsnckTask Class :

```
public class AsyncTaskWebServiceCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

Activity mActivity;
Context context;

// LoginActivity MyClass = new LoginActivity();
// public static Context contextOfApplication;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

// Context applicationContext = LoginActivity.getContextOfApplication();

// Constractor
public AsyncTaskWebServiceCaller(Activity activity,
        ProgressDialog progressDialog, Context context) {
    super();
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    this.mActivity = activity;
    this.context = context;
}

// BackGround Process
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    // this is executed in a background thread.
    // the result is returned to the UI thread via onPostExecute

    try {
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.sams.com";
        final String URL = "http://88.198.82.92:8080/sams1/services/LoginActvityWs?WSDL"; // usint
                                                                                            // //
                                                                                            // localhost
        final String METHOD_NAME = "login";
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.sams.com/login";
        final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        final HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                URL);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.mActivity);
        String user = prefs.getString("login", null);
        String pass = prefs.getString("password", null);
        // Calling Login Method
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        // First Reques for USER NAME .
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("username");
        pi.setValue(user);
        pi.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);

        // Second Reques for USER NAME .
        PropertyInfo pi2 = new PropertyInfo();
        pi2.setName("password");
        pi2.setValue(pass);
        pi2.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi2);

        // Getting Request Result , Will get TID .
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        return response.toString();

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

        return e.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        return e.toString();
    }

    catch (NullPointerException e) {

        return e.toString();

    }

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), result,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // If any error oceeared duaring get TID
    if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("error")) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                mActivity);

        alertDialog.setTitle("يوجد مشكلة بالاتصال او السيرفر");
        alertDialog.setMessage("هل تود المحاولة مجددا ؟ ");
        // Retry Button Action
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("نعم",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        AsyncTaskWebServiceCaller asynTask = new AsyncTaskWebServiceCaller(
                                mActivity, progressDialog, mActivity
                                        .getApplicationContext());
                        asynTask.execute();
                    }
                });

        // No Button Action
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("لا",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.show();

    }
    // IF pass or user Filed .
    else if (Integer.parseInt(result.toString()) == 0) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                mActivity);

        alertDialog.setTitle("اسم المستخدم او كلمة المرور خاطئة");
        alertDialog.setMessage("هل تود اعادة تسجيل الدخول ");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("نعم",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("لا",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(),
                                "thank you for using SAMS app",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mActivity.finish();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.show();

    }

    // For correct Login !
    else {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(),
                result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (Integer.parseInt(result.toString()) == 1) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(mActivity, DashBoard.class);
            mActivity.startActivity(intent1);

        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Look at your logcat, find the location of the NPE, and figure out which null object you're attempting to access. Then fix it.

Comment: Good that you posted your code, but you should really consider posting the full stack trace. It will tell you (or the SO community) where exactly your NPE is thrown, which will make it possible to help you debug your code.

Comment: what all above said :)) and check your new Intent parameters are not going in as null.

Comment: i have added the full log trace

Comment: Activities are not instantiated it is started from intent 
In log cat it is instantiating activity Components

Comment: The stack trace tells you the NPE is thrown at line 79 of your `LoginActivity`. You should check there, or provide the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:139)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:65)
    at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:142)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:359)
    at com.hesham.sams.LoginActivity.<init>(LoginActivity.java:79)
```

Reading from bottom up. Your `LoginActivity` initialization, either constructor or member variable initialization, instantiates an `AlertDialog.Builder`. It takes in a `Context` argument. However, activity initialization is too early in the lifecycle to use the activity object as a `Context`. You will have to delay your `AlertDialog.Builder` initialization (and everything else that needs a `Context`) until `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

First Look at your intent . The way you are opening a new activity.

it should be

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(mActivity.this, DashBoard.class);
        mActivity.startActivity(intent1);
```

Comment: this may or may not be the issue coz individually mActivity will also work

Comment: not working i have used >> Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.mActivity, DashBoard.class);

Comment: it is mActivity.this not this.mActivity